# How to change the colours of the lateral kde plots of seaborn jointplot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn, kernel-density, density-plot

I want to create a `sns.jointplot` that uses the standard colormap `"Greens"`. The output of this standard colorcycle is too light for the lateral kde estimated densities. I would prefer the darker colours you get when you use the `"BuGn_r"` colormap.

Is there an easy way to get them darker?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pn
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
with sns.axes_style("white"):
    sns.set_palette("BuGn_r")
    g2 = sns.jointplot("sepal_width", "petal_length", data=iris,
                kind="kde", space=0)

with sns.axes_style("white"):
    sns.set_palette("Greens")
    g3 = sns.jointplot("sepal_width", "petal_length", data=iris,
                    kind="kde", space=0)
```

See the output below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the colour of the line and shaded region after you create it with `kdeplot`. The marginal axes can be accessed from `g3`, by `g3.ax_marg_x` and `g3.ax_marg_y`.

You can change the colour of the line with:

```
g3.ax_marg_x.lines[0].set_color()
```

And the colour of the shaded region with:

```
g3.ax_marg_x.collections[0].set_facecolor()
```

Of course, you could set these to any valid `matplotlib` colour. Or, to get the exact colours that you use in your first plot, you could also use `get_color` and `get_facecolor` on the `g2` marginals.

You can see it all in action in the script below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pn
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
with sns.axes_style("white"):
    sns.set_palette("BuGn_r")
    g2 = sns.jointplot("sepal_width", "petal_length", data=iris,
                kind="kde", space=0)

    # Find out the face and line colours that BuGn_r uses
    facecolor = g2.ax_marg_x.collections[0].get_facecolor()
    linecolor = g2.ax_marg_x.lines[0].get_color()

    print facecolor 
    # [[ 0.0177624   0.4426759   0.18523645  0.25      ]]

    print linecolor
    # (0.017762399946942051, 0.44267590116052069, 0.18523645330877866)    

with sns.axes_style("white"):
    sns.set_palette("Greens")
    g3 = sns.jointplot("sepal_width", "petal_length", data=iris,
                    kind="kde", space=0)

    # Change the facecolor of the shaded region under the line
    g3.ax_marg_x.collections[0].set_facecolor(facecolor)
    g3.ax_marg_y.collections[0].set_facecolor(facecolor)

    # And change the line colour.
    g3.ax_marg_x.lines[0].set_color(linecolor)
    g3.ax_marg_y.lines[0].set_color(linecolor)

plt.show()
```

### "BuGn_r"

[image]

### "Greens" with modified colours

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `color=` parameter of `jointplot`.

Comment: up to my knowledge the color= parameter changes the color of both, the central contour AND the lateral densities. If you have any further information just let me know!